# How to display pictures, video, text, and audio all on the same view on the iphone?

Tags: iphone, video, text, audio, uiimageview

I am trying to have a view that has four buttons on the top: a picture button, video button, audio button, and text button and an imageView below the buttons. If you click on the picture button, the imageView displays the picture. but if I click the video button i want the imageView to display a picture of the video that you can click and play the video. The audio button would do the same and the text button should display the text in the view.

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is because I don't know if you can add anything to a UIImageView or if I should put views on top of eachother in interface builder.

any advice is appreciated.

Comment: may be you should consider invoking media player for handling audio and video..

Answer (score 0):

Hav you tried using a UITabBarViewController? I think this may be what you're looking for. A quick Google search came up with the following tutorial: http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/create-uitabbarcontroller/